# C# Performance: Few Long Running Tasks vs Many Short Running Tasks

Tags: c#, performance, task, task-parallel-library

Given a simple program, what would be better from a performance/throughput point of view and *why* would it be better from a performance point of view?
(I don't care about memory consumption or CPU usage)

Assuming it takes roughly 5 ms to process a given message and there are ~500 messages received every second.
What should give better performance?

1. 50 long running tasks that each receive and process ~10 messages per second
2. To create and run a new task for each message received

I am wondering with regard to running on a regular ~8 cores PC and not a 100+ core super computer.

Just to clarify; In the 50 long running tasks scenario most of the tasks would most of the time be waiting for a message and once received they would be signaled to wake up while in the creating new tasks scenario there would be ~500 tasks created every second.

Comment: When you measured both options on your specific target hardware and operating environment, which one was faster? That's your answer.

Comment: "*2. To create and run a new task for each message received*": Could you add more info about the mechanism that receives messages and assigns them to tasks?

Comment: Personally I prefer to run a new task for each message. I got the cases in the past and it was faster (but it's probably not a rule for anything) but it's also easier to recover in case of failure. If one task fail we just need to rerun the message. If a message in a batch failed, it's more difficult to run the entire batch.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question with the (lack of) information provided. What does the application do? How can you care but not care about performance at the same time? `from a performance point of view? (I don't care about memory consumption or CPU usage)` but that's what performance means - use the given RAM and CPU cores to process messages more efficiently. If the CPU is blocked, the program will be slow. If the CPU is busy allocating RAM and garbage collecting, it's not processing messages

Comment: Besides, what does processing a message mean? If you need to perform IO, you need tasks. If you await, you use Tasks. Tasks aren't threads, so having a lot of them doesn't mean you'll have a lot of threads. Having 1000 IO-related tasks doesn't mean your CPU will block. Calling a remote server that can't handle more than 5 concurrent calls though, will block you one way or another

Comment: A Task is a *promise* that something will complete in the future. It's not a thread, so it doesn't really matter how many you use, it's what you do with them. They're pretty small and lightweight objects, but they still need to be garbage-collected. To reduce the overhead use `ValueTask`, don't try to change how your application operates. That's how ASP.NET Core manages to score so high in benchmarks - not by using long tasks, but by reducing blocking and the RAM/GC overhead

Comment: Another far more important bottleneck is memory allocations - allocating a buffer and GCing it is far more expensive than allocating/GCing a task. You can improve performance A LOT by using MemoryPool/ArrayPool and reuse buffers instead of allocating new ones

Comment: `once received they would be signaled to wake up` that's what `await` is for. You can use a TaskCompletionSource to adopt event-based or callback-based APIs to the asynchronous model. What you assume would be one long running task is probably a long running *loop* that uses multiple tasks internally for async IO operations and awaits.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to predict.  Depends a lot on how you are processing messages, how CPU cache comes into play, how CPU-intensive message processing is, what the IO activity is.  The only reliable approach is to [benchmark](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) your code and see what works better.  Keep in mind that the results can be heavily influenced by other processes that run on this computer.  Try to emulate your production environment as much as possible.